# VBA Copy a table of user input data to a database tab, based on the employees name

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a tab in excel where managers can input their forecast of Holidays, Sickness, Training and other lost time for the next 4 months.

To make this smoother I've made it so they select their own name and their team shows in the table and they can input the lost days for the team.

What I'm having issues with is the code that then takes this information and copies it to another tab, and puts it in against the right employee. This data tab has every employee so it needs to search down column B for the matching name and copy the data into the corresponding columns. I've tried a few different ways but none quite do what i'm looking for

First image is the screen the manager sees to enter their forecast of lost days

second image is the screen that the data needs to be copied into the archive it for it to be used elsewhere

[image: Table where Manager enters their teams data]

[image: Table where the data needs to be copied to]
Hopefully this coveres my query, any help would be wonderful

Closest code I could get working below, only copies 1 value and for only 1 employee however

```
Sub Find_First()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = Sheets("Calc").Range("G7").Value
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("DATA Build").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
        Sheets("Calc").Range("I31").Copy Sheets("DATA Build").Cells(Rng.Row, "BD")
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your code!  We can't help you fix it if we can't see it.

Comment: I don't really have any code that would be beneficial as I've not managed to find anything that is doing what I need. I'll add the code i found that does a similar thing ,to the post

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the second tab is an aggregated view of the first (@ manager level)?

Comment: yep, that will show the teams of all managers, this is then used to vlookup against in another tab

Comment: What version of Excel as you using? This sounds like a userform/dataform kind of task or even one for Access.

Comment: And generally avoid working with merged cells as will make finding and working with some of your ranges that little bit more difficult. (Or have a hidden row that is not merged that you reference).

Comment: Personally, I'd solve this problem using Excel formulas or PowerQuery transformations.  There's nothing wrong with VBA, but you'll end up writing a lot more code this way.  Always a little tricky answering Excel Qs, as we don't have the spreadsheet and they are not easy to share.  Main issue with your code is this line `FindString = Sheets("Calc").Range("G7").Value`.  It limits you to 1 row.  Replacing this with a loop would be a great start.